# Generating a Nested Set Model from a POJO

Tags: javascript, nested-sets, nested-set-model

I have been playing around with some Nested Set Models (NSM). One thing I wanted to do is to be able to generate a NSM from a given JavaScript object.

For example, given the following object:

```
var data = {
  Clothes: {
    Jackets: {
      Waterproof: true,
      Insulated: true
    },
    Hats: true,
    Socks: true
  },
}
```

I'd like to generate an array of objects like so.

```
[
  {
    "name": "Clothes",
    "lft": 1,
    "rgt": 12
  },
  {
    "name": "Jackets",
    "lft": 2,
    "rgt": 7
  },
  {
    "name": "Waterproof",
    "lft": 3,
    "rgt": 4
  },
  {
    "name": "Insulated",
    "lft": 5,
    "rgt": 6
  },
  {
    "name": "Hats",
    "lft": 8,
    "rgt": 9
  },
  {
    "name": "Socks",
    "lft": 10,
    "rgt": 11
  }
]
```

That is - a depth first walk through the object, assigning an ID and counting the left and right edge for each object in the hierarchy. So that each node has a unique ID and the correct `lft` and `rgt` values for a NSM.

I've tried various approaches but just can't seem to get the result I am after...I had some success by altering the model to use properties for the node name and child nodes - i.e.

```js
var data2 = {
  name: "Clothes",
  children: [{
      name: "Jackets",
      children: [{
        name: "Waterproof",
      }, {
        name: "Insulated"
      }]
    }, {
      name: "Hats"
    },
    {
      name: "Socks"
    }
  ]
};

function nestedSet(o, c, l = 0) {
  let n = {
    name: o.name,
    lft: l + 1
  };
  c.push(n);
  let r = n.lft;
  for (var x in o.children) {
    r = nestedSet(o.children[x], c, r);
  }

  n.rgt = r + 1;

  return n.rgt;
}

let out = [];
nestedSet(data2, out);
console.log(out)
```

This gives the correct result but requires altering the input data...is there a way to generate the same Nested Set Model using the original `data` object?

Comment: Take a look at `Object.entries`. If you call `Object.entries({ a: 1, b: 2 })` you get `[['a', 1], ['b', 2]]`. For example, recursively applying `transform = x => Object.entries(x).map(([k, v]) => ({ name: k, children: v !== true ? transform(v) : undefined }))` would transform the original `data` to the structure you are using now. So in the next step you can use this idea by iterating over the data this way in the first place instead of transforming.

Comment: @CherryDT Hmm an interesting approach - will have a play with it - thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually managed to solve this in the end...I just forgot about it for a long while! Basically all that is required is to reclusively pass the `Object.entries` as kindly suggested in @CherryDT's comment. This way one can resolve the name/children to build the nested set model as required.

```js
var data = {
    Clothes: {
        Jackets: {
            Waterproof: {},
            Insulated: {},
        },
        Hats: {},
        Socks: {},
    },
};

function ns(node, stack = [], lft = 0) {
    var rgt = ++lft;
    var item = {
        name: node[0],
        lft: lft,
    };
    stack.push(item);
    Object.entries(node[1]).forEach(function (c) {
        rgt = ns(c, stack, rgt);
    });
    item.rgt = ++rgt;
    return rgt;
}

var result = [];
ns(Object.entries(data)[0], result);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks to @CherryDT for the tip!